# java. inheritance/polymorphism, quiz error?

Tags: java

this was off a review quiz to help me understand the material but the answer just got me confused.

// question 10

What will this program print out?

```
class Base{

int value = 0; 
Base(){

addValue();

}
void addValue(){

value += 10;

}

int getValue(){

return value;

}

}

class Derived extends Base{

Derived(){

addValue();

}

void addValue(){

value += 20;

}

}

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){

Base b = new Derived();
System.out.println(b.getValue());

}

}
```

it is in java. the answer comes to 40? I couldn't understand why.

Comment: What don't you understand? 20+20=40

Comment: Is there a `main`?  How is this being run?

Comment: [No attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt). At least you should post what you believe to and what is your answer so we can point out what's wrong with your answer.

Comment: Shubhendu Pramanik explained it below. I thought the value would come to 20. I didn't know the subclass would call the bass class default constructor when it extends it. Yes, there is a main. In the class Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what's happening is when you call `Base b = new Derived()` it first calls `Derived()` on derived class. Now as `Derived` class extends `Base` class every constructor of `Derived` class internally
calls the default cunstructor of base class, similer to

```
Derived() {
        super();
        addValue();
    }
```

which in turns calls the `Base()`. Now inside `Base()` `addValue()` is there. As the instanse is of `Derived` class the `addValue()` method is called from the `Derived` class(Read ***Overriding*** and ***Dynamic Method Dispatcher***)
    so `value` becomes `value+20= i.e. 20`. Then when returning fromm `Base()` it gets `addValue()` again inside `Derived()`. So it again calls `addValue()` and value of `value` becomes `(20+20)`.

***N.B.: You really need to read a lot about Polymorphism, Dynamic method dispatcher for this.***

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that the subclass calls the default constructor of base class when it extends it. The text book we are using hasn't gone that far into polymorphism. I will look up the net for dynamic method dispatcher though.